# Display Array item using its Index value

Tags: javascript, angular

I've function `showEmployee(i)` which returns me the index of an array object.

Using the index value i need to show the value of that returned index.

I could not figure out how to do it. I tired `congole.log(i)` which returns `undefined`

Below is my code. Please help

```
Employees =[
    {'name':'Arun','role':'Developer'},
    ....
  ];

showEmployee(i){
   console.log(i); // this returns the index value of the array
}
```

Comment: your `i` is the current object in the array ?

Comment: 'i' is index? currect list? current object?

Comment: it's incomplete code. and incomplete and unclear question. need to be edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the method to do this in Javascript, we can access array element by doing `<<arrayName>>[<<index of the array element>>]`, please refer the below snippet and let me know if this fixes your issue!

if you want to return a specific value in the array, you can do `return Employees[i].name` or `return Employees[i].role` in the `showEmployee()` function.

**Note:**

1. variables like (`Employees`) need to defined using the syntax `var << variable name >> = <<something>>`.
2. functions should be defined like

   ```
   function <<function name>>(<< function parameters){

    }
   ```

```js
var Employees = [
    {'name':'Arun','role':'Developer'},
    {'name':'Arun2','role':'Developer2'},
    {'name':'Arun3','role':'Developer3'},
    {'name':'Arun4','role':'Developer4'},
    {'name':'Arun5','role':'Developer5'}
  ];

function showEmployee(i){
   console.log(Employees[i]); // this returns the index value of the array
}

showEmployee(2);
showEmployee(3);
showEmployee(4);
```

```css
.as-console {
    height: 100%;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```